# Traversing/comparing tree structures with only parent references

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, graph, tree

Consider a tree structure with nodes containing references to only their parent. So, the root node's parent will be null. This tree represents a class hierarchy. The goal is to search such a tree for a particular subtree, and if it doesn't exist, add it to the tree. Is there an algorithm that can be used to achieve this?

In this particular case, I have a C# WinForms application which uses this kind of structure. At the moment, an iterative breadth-first traversal is being used to traverse through such a tree and display it as a `treeView`. How this is being done is as follows: To represent the nodes of the tree itself, there is a class `Data_Node`. To perform the traversal, the nodes are placed into a queue. The queue contains instances of a data structure, `QueueNode`:

```
private class QueueNode
{
    public Model.Data_node dataNode; // actual tree node
    public QueueNode parent; // reference to the parent
    public TreeNode treeNode; // node for treeView in the UI
}
```

The next step is to implement another such tree (assume it is already, then check whether it is a subtree of the first one, and add it if it is not.

I have researched examples of what I am trying to achieve, but they were only for binary search trees, with nodes having references to the child nodes. In my case, the nodes only have references to the parent node.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but the way it works is as follows. The nodes for the tree itself are of a type `Data_Node` which is defined in the code. To perform the traversal with the breadth-first search, a data structure `QueueNode` is defined, which has properties: dataNode of type `Data_Node`, and parent of type `QueueNode`. I hope that makes sense. I can add some code to the question if that would help.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense why parents don't know about their children. You'll have to keep references to the children somewhere anyway, or how else are you going to access them? In any way, I doubt there's a commonly known algorithm for whatever you are trying to do (since the problem itself isn't that common).

Comment: i am not sure how trees referencing their parents are any different from trees referencing their children. Change the word itself, and you have yourself a tree with children. Algorithm for searching down the children node would be the same as the one you have here. You are looking at it upside down but mechanics are the same

Comment: @Jawad tree has one root... If you flip tree upside-down it will no longer have one root... Now for "tree with only parent refs" one must know list of all leaf nodes to be able to walk the tree... and walking have to be done carefully to not visit parents multiple times... I don't think algorithm to walk such tree would be as simple as regular breads first search for tree.

Comment: There are use cases for the scenario that OP has mentioned and there are certainly cases where parent doesn't know its children(which is why my search landed me here), however I have references to all leaf nodes, so I could traverse all the elements in the tree back to the root